# php Error trying to make a OOP login system

Tags: php, database, authentication

I keep getting the warning error while trying to make this object oriented log in system. I am trying to do the insert function right now but the warning is stopping me.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\YetiDraft\yetidb\classes\db.php on line 32

Line 32 is the function query foreach statement

```
<?php

class db {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query, 
            $_error = false, 
            $_results, 
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new db();
        }
        return self::$_instance;

    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                        $x++;
                }   
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            }else{
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }


    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()){
        if(count($where) === 3){
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=',);

            $field = $where[0];
            $operator = $where[1];
            $value = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where){
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function delete($table, $where){
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()){
        if(count($fields)){
            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = '';
            $x = 1;

            foreach($fields as $fields){
                $values .= "?";
                if($x < count($fields)){
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) ."`) VALUES ({$values})";

            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function results(){
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function first(){
        return $this->results()[0];
    }

    public function error(){
        return $this->_error;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }

}



?>
```

Comment: Kishor I assume you mean var_dump($params)?

Comment: You are not giving enough info ... what are you calling the class with?

Comment: can you `var_dump($params)` and see whats the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part might cause the problem:

```
foreach($fields as $fields){
    $values .= "?";
    if($x < count($fields)){
         $values .= ', ';
    }
    $x++;
}
```

You are using the variable `$fields` both as source and as iterator.

Doing so overwrites `$fields` with the last element of the array. For this reason, in the following call, `$fields` is not an array anymore:

```
if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
```

And since you are trying to iterate over the value of `$fields` in `$this->query()`, you are getting the error.

*Thanks to Barmar for the tip!*

---

Try this instead:

```
foreach($fields as $field){
    $values .= "?";
    if($x < count($fields)){
         $values .= ', ';
    }
    $x++;
}
```

**Edit:** Or use Barmar's solution instead. His solution is better.

Comment: That's not the line that's getting the error, and it won't cause an error. `foreach` saves the array internally, so it doesn't cause a problem if you reuse the variable. It's just confusing to human readers (like you).

Comment: Actually, it's causing the problem indirectly. He then calls `$this->query($sql, $fields)` from that function. At this point `$fields` contains the last field, not the original array.

Comment: In your answer, `count($field)` should be `count($fields)` -- he wants to avoid adding a `,` when he's adding the last field to the string.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the tip, did not know that. Learning something new every day! :-) I just tested it, and as you said, it does cause the issue indirectly. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$params` isnt an array and hence isnt traversable. Make a small check before the foreach like this.

```
    if (is_array($params))
    {
    foreach ($params as $param)
    {
    //do things here
    }
    }
```

`count()` is not a reliable way to check if a variable is an array. Use `is_array` instead of `count()`. Your error probably is the variable isnt an array, and you are trying to traverse through the variable.

Comment: That will get rid of the error, but won't make the code work.

Comment: he needs to fix the problem that's causing `$params` not to be an array in the first place.

Comment: Yes. I asked him to do a var_dump, and he is yet to respond.

Comment: But there's enough information in the code to tell what it will be. It will be a string containing the value of the last field being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the loop:

```
foreach($fields as $field){
    $values .= "?";
    if($x < count($field)){
         $values .= ', ';
    }
    $x++;
}
```

with

```
$values = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($fields), '?'));
```

Because you're reusing the variable `$fields` as the iteration variable, when your loop is done `$fields` no longer contains an array of fields, it contains the value of the last field. So when you call `$this->query($sql, $fields)`, you're passing a string instead of an array, and the `foreach` inside `query()` won't work.

Comment: The error is occuring in line 32. Thats the foreach above the one you are quoting. This is the line `foreach($params as $param) {`

Comment: I understand. It's receiving the `$params` argument from this code. Because of this error, `$params` is a string instead of an array like it should be.